# Spring webflux - Running job one after other

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I am using Spring webflux and run multiple jobs. Each job will connect to an analytical DB and run a query which could take about 30 mins. I need to run 200 such jobs and I can have only 10 connections to DB. So, With the approach below, getting "HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30005ms" as 10 connections are already being in use and other queries in the queue is timing out. What is the alternative approach to handle this?

```
private Mono<String> runJobs(final ReconDto req) {
return jobRepo.fetchJobs().collectList()
                               .zipWhen((jobs) -> Flux.fromIterable(jobs)
                                                        .flatMap((job) -> runJob( job)).collectList())
                               .flatMap(response -> {
                                   return Mono.just(req.getJobName());
                               });
}

private Mono<String> runJob(final JobMeta job) {
  // Here connecting to an analytical DB and running a query which might take 30 mins or so.
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use an appropriate framework?

Comment: Unfortunately, Spring webflux is the option for me go with and checking the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concurrency` param of the `flatMap` to limit maximum number of in-flight inner publishers.

```
Mono<String> runJobs(final ReconDto req) {
    return jobRepo.fetchJobs()
            .flatMap(job -> runJob(job), 10)
            .then(Mono.just(req.getJobName()));
}
```

In non-reactive terms this is analog of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 10 threads.